# Parsing json string with multiple objects

Tags: android, json

How can I parse the following to retrieve the following.

```
{"docs": [
    "SolrDocument[{content_type=[text/plain], description=/mnt/sdcard/A.txt, id=4df6fa43-1a99-4475-bc5b-80dd0ab6d114, name=uploadedfile}]",
    "SolrDocument[{content_type=[text/plain], description=asdf.png, id=9fb20d5d-cf39-4635-9a22-64560124809e, name=uploadedfile}]"]
}
```

I need to retrieve description into a string array and id to another string array.
I tried

```
a="docs"
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(line);
JSONArray IDS = (JSONArray) jobj.get(a);
```

This works but it returns an array of strings

Comment: The json really only represents a list containing two strings. You will then need to use regular expressions to get the description out of the strings.

Comment: The strings inside `docs` aren't valid JSON.  They are missing quotes around the string values (and keys depending on how strict your JSON parser is) and `:` separating the keys

Comment: @JasonSperske Hey can you please give me the work around for that. I am really in need of it

Comment: @user1494754 This should get you started :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data you are trying to parse isn't valid JSON, so you are now in RegEx territory.  So reading each line out of the JSONArray you could extract what you are after like this:

```
String data = "SolrDocument[{content_type=[text/plain], description=/mnt/sdcard/A.txt, id=4df6fa43-1a99-4475-bc5b-80dd0ab6d114, name=uploadedfile}]";
Pattern values = Pattern.compile("(description|id)=([\\S]+),", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matches = values.matcher(data);
while(matches.find()) {
  System.out.println(matches.group(1) + "=" + matches.group(2));
}
```

This will print out:

```
description=/mnt/sdcard/A.txt
id=4df6fa43-1a99-4475-bc5b-80dd0ab6d114
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements inside the JSONArray "docs" are not valid JSON objects. You must have "key":"value" pairs in order to be valid.

For example:

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "id": 912345678901,
            "text": "How do I read JSON on Android?",
            "geo": null,
            "user": {
                "name": "android_newb",
                "followers_count": 41
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 912345678902,
            "text": "@android_newb just use android.util.JsonReader!",
            "geo": [
                50.454722,
                -104.606667
            ],
            "user": {
                "name": "jesse",
                "followers_count": 2
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

There are plenty of sites that can validate your JSON, for example [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com)

Before we can answer your question, fix your JSON.

Comment: I understand. Here I need to parse the string then to get all the values of description and ids into string arrays